# Discrepancy in the series expansion of BesselK[ν, z]

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I am trying to expand the modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_{\nu}(z)$ for small values of the argument $z$ keeping $\nu$ fixed.

Mathematica 12.2.0 says that it is

```
  In[1]:=  Normal[Series[(BesselK[\[Nu], \[Alpha]*z]), {z, 0, 1}, 
       Assumptions -> {\[Alpha] > 0, Abs[\[Nu]] > 0, 
         Abs[z] > 0}]] // Expand 
    
  Out[1]:=  2^(-1 - \[Nu]) z^\[Nu] \[Alpha]^\[Nu] Gamma[-\[Nu]] + 
     2^(-1 + \[Nu]) z^-\[Nu] \[Alpha]^-\[Nu] Gamma[\[Nu]]
```

So, Mathematica essentially tells me that there are two terms, viz.,

$$ K_{\nu} \sim \dfrac{1}{2}\Gamma\bigl(\nu\bigl)\Bigl(\dfrac{1}{2}z\Bigl)^{-\nu}+\dfrac{1}{2}\Gamma\bigl(-\nu\bigl)\Bigl(\dfrac{1}{2}z\Bigl)^{\nu}, ~ z \to 0.$$

However, this seemingly **does not agree** with result quoted in *Abramowitz and Stegun* (and in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms)). According to Abramowitz and Stegun, it is

$$K_{\nu} \sim \dfrac{1}{2}\Gamma\bigl(\nu\bigl)\Bigl(\dfrac{1}{2}z\Bigl)^{-\nu}, ~z \to 0, ~ \mathrm{if}  ~ \nu>0. $$

**What is the reason behind this discrepancy?** Does this have something  to with the fact $K_{-\nu}(z)=K_{\nu}(z)$?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the modulus of `2^(-1 - \[Nu]) z^\[Nu] \[Alpha]^\[Nu] Gamma[-\[Nu]]` approaches zero as `z` tends to zero, whereas the modulus of `\[Nu]) z^-\[Nu] \[Alpha]^-\[Nu] Gamma[\[Nu]]` tends to infinity as `z` tends to zero. The result of MMA is in accordance with Abramowitz and Stegun. Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: It is because you only looked at pt. 9.6.9 of Abramowitz and Stegun where only the main term is given. If you look at pt. 9.6.11 you find a more complete expression.

Comment: I don't see a discrepancy. One is restricted to `\[Nu]>0`, the other is not.

Comment: @DanielLichtblay: If $\nu>0$, then  $$ K_{\nu} \sim \dfrac{1}{2}\Gamma\bigl(\nu\bigl)\Bigl(\dfrac{1}{2}z\Bigl)^{-\nu}+\dfrac{1}{2}\Gamma\bigl(-\nu\bigl)\Bigl(\dfrac{1}{2}z\Bigl)^{\nu}, ~ z \to 0,$$ implies $$K_{\nu} \sim \dfrac{1}{2}\Gamma\bigl(\nu\bigl)\Bigl(\dfrac{1}{2}z\Bigl)^{-\nu}, ~z \to 0,$$ as is noticed in my comment.